# SpriteKit - Detect if node hits another nodes children and perform action

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I have a Cat node, and a Bird node. The bird nodes are nested together in a container node called a birdBlock. Everything is contained in a WorldNode. If I add a bird to the WorldNode, the Cat can interact with it appropriately, but when the birds are in the birdBlock, the Cat just shoves them out of the way and they go flying.

I am using the following to find my birds:

```
[worldNode enumerateChildNodesWithName:kBirdName usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
{
    SKSpriteNode *newBird = (SKSpriteNode *)node;
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(newBird.frame,cat.frame))
    { 
       //Do Something
       //This is never reached when the birds are in the SKSpriteNode birdBlock. 
       //They just get shoved all over the screen.
    }
}];
```

The birds in the block have the correct name.

They are now being enumerated, but still do not interact with the cat other than flying around the screen.

Now I am doing this:

```
[[worldNode children] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
        SKSpriteNode *blockNode = (SKSpriteNode *)obj;
        if ([blockNode.name isEqualToString:kBirdBlockName])
        {
            [blockNode enumerateChildNodesWithName:kBirdName usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
            {
                SKSpriteNode *nbird = (SKSpriteNode *)node;
                NSLog(@"FOUND BIRDS HERE");

                //THIS IS FOUND! But below still does not work

                if (CGRectIntersectsRect(nbird.frame, cat.frame))
                {
                    NSLog(@"Hit BIRD");
                    [nbird removeFromParent];
                }
            }
        }
}];
```

So this does not work either. How do you change the coordinate system of a sprite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this to work, so I just gave all the birds a physicsBody, and moved the detection to `didBeginContact`

Now it does not matter what their parent is and I don't need to worry about changing coordinates.

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKSpriteNode *firstNode = (SKSpriteNode *)contact.bodyA.node;
    SKSpriteNode *secondNode = (SKSpriteNode *) contact.bodyB.node;
    if ((firstNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == catCategory && secondNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == birdCategory) || (firstNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == birdCategory && secondNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == catCategory))
    {
        NSLog(@"DID HIT BIRD");
        if (firstNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == catCategory) {
            //do something to secondNode.
        }
        if (firstNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == birdCategory) {
            //do something to firstNode.
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search the node tree in many ways. The [SKNode documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html) explains it clearly under the section *Searching the Node Tree*.

If you have a node named **@"node"** then you can search through all descendants by putting a **//** before the name. So you would search for **@"//node"**.

Try changing your constant **kBirdName** to equal **@"//my_bird_name"**

An example using a string literal would be -

```
[worldNode enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"//nodeName" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
{ // Do stuff here... }
```

Comment: The literal does not seem to work, and seems to break the birds that are not in the block as well. Now the cat sends them all flying instead of performing the interaction that I want.

Comment: Are the birds in the nest turning up in the block? Also where you detect the frame intersection, make sure the rects are in the same nodes coordinate space. cat.frame is in the scene coordinates i'm assuming but newBird.frame is in its parents coordinate space which is not the scene (if its in a nest). Upon collision you may also need to remove the bird from parent, convert position and add to scene, depending on what behaviour you are wanting.

Comment: What do you mean by turning up? They are visible and go flying when the Cat hits them. How do I make them in the same coordinate space?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion - By turning up I meant in code do all bird nodes get discovered now from the method you posted and get passed into the block via the SKNode *node argument. SKNode has a couple of methods for converting coordinates to that of other nodes. The methods to use are convertPoint:fromNode: and convertPoint:toNode:

Comment: The birds are not being enumerated. How do you enumerate children's children?

Comment: Ok I updated my question with my new code. This somehow seems like the hard way to me. I now think it might have to be with coordinate conversion issues.